# Calculation of angle between turtle and patch

Tags: netlogo

How do I calculate the above angle specified in the figure.
The patch is known beforehand.
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I won't write code for it, but here is a general recipe:

- Find the four corner points of the patch by adding/subtracting 0.5 from [`pxcor`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#pxcor) and [`pycor`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#pycor);
- Find the closest two corners by using [`distancexy`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#distancexy);
- Find the heading of each of those two points by using [`towardsxy`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#towardsxy);
- Compute the difference between these two headings by using [`subtract-headings`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#subtract-headings).

Answer (score 1):

```
to-report calculate-turtles-in-cone2
  let px [pxcor] of patch-goal
  let py [pycor] of patch-goal
 ; show  [pxcor] of patch-goal
  set corner-1 list (px + 0.5 - .25)(py - 0.5)
  set corner-2 list (px - 0.5 + .25)(py - 0.5)
; show corner-1 
; show corner-2
  let head-1 towardsxy (item 0 corner-1) (item 1 corner-1)
  let head-2 towardsxy (item 0 corner-2) (item 1 corner-2)
  report abs (subtract-headings head-1 head-2)  
end
```